# Places Autocomplete Android

Tags: android, autocomplete, google-places-api, autocompletetextview

I am new to Android development.

I'am struggling a while to autocomplete the userinput. I need a google maps like auto-completion for the user input. The user need to be select a address, place, street a.s.o. from the auto complete and i need the LatLng of it.

I tried to get this done by using the google [course](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete#add_an_autocomplete_widget) but this is not exactly what i want. I don't wanna have a whole fragment or something what is used only for selecting a place, I'm looking for a `AutoCompleteTextView` solution. Is there a easy to understand way to do this?

I found [this](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-google-places-autocomplete-api-example/) but this looks not like the "normal way" to do this or are i'm wrong? This is a web API call instead of a Android API call isn't it?

**--------------------------------UPDATE-----------------------------**

My manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="aaeu.app">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>


    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <application
        android:name="com.activeandroid.app.Application"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".presentationlayer.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".presentationlayer.AlertDetailActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>


        <meta-data
            android:name="AA_DB_NAME"
            android:value="local_test_db.db" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="AA_DB_VERSION"
            android:value="9" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="AA_MODELS"
            android:value="aaeu.app.datalayer.Alert , aaeu.app.datalayer.Area" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="XXXXXXBsWU9seEWmlB-CMc_pxZ358b4-esTNR5I" />
<!-- without this meta-data below the app don't crash but sais API key wrong -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="XXXXXXBsWU9seEWmlB-CMc_pxZ358b4-esTNR5I" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: are you want your auto complete text view show only that suggestion which user has used.

Comment: look at similar question.
[Getting started with google Place Autocomplete API call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20795326/getting-started-with-google-place-autocomplete-api-call?rq=1)

Comment: probably, you can use library https://github.com/mobisystech/autocompleteview..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this to create custom Places Suggestion and process the data. Below is the Activity which shows Places Suggestion in an `AutoCompleteTextView`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "MainActivity";
    private static final int GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID = 0;
    private AutoCompleteTextView mAutocompleteTextView;
    private TextView mNameTextView;
    private TextView mAddressTextView;
    private TextView mIdTextView;
    private TextView mPhoneTextView;
    private TextView mWebTextView;
    private TextView mAttTextView;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private PlaceArrayAdapter mPlaceArrayAdapter;
    private static final LatLngBounds BOUNDS_MOUNTAIN_VIEW = new LatLngBounds(
            new LatLng(37.398160, -122.180831), new LatLng(37.430610, -121.972090));

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .enableAutoManage(this, GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID, this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .build();
        mAutocompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id
                .autoCompleteTextView);
        mAutocompleteTextView.setThreshold(3);
        mNameTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        mAddressTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.address);
        mIdTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.place_id);
        mPhoneTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.phone);
        mWebTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.web);
        mAttTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.att);
        mAutocompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(mAutocompleteClickListener);
        mPlaceArrayAdapter = new PlaceArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                BOUNDS_MOUNTAIN_VIEW, null);
        mAutocompleteTextView.setAdapter(mPlaceArrayAdapter);
    }

    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mAutocompleteClickListener
            = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            final PlaceArrayAdapter.PlaceAutocomplete item = mPlaceArrayAdapter.getItem(position);
            final String placeId = String.valueOf(item.placeId);
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Selected: " + item.description);
            PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi
                    .getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, placeId);
            placeResult.setResultCallback(mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback);
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Fetching details for ID: " + item.placeId);
        }
    };

    private ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer> mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback
            = new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
            if (!places.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Place query did not complete. Error: " +
                        places.getStatus().toString());
                return;
            }
            // Selecting the first object buffer.
            final Place place = places.get(0);
            CharSequence attributions = places.getAttributions();

            mNameTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(place.getName() + ""));
            mAddressTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(place.getAddress() + ""));
            mIdTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(place.getId() + ""));
            mPhoneTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(place.getPhoneNumber() + ""));
            mWebTextView.setText(place.getWebsiteUri() + "");
            if (attributions != null) {
                mAttTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(attributions.toString()));
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mPlaceArrayAdapter.setGoogleApiClient(mGoogleApiClient);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Google Places API connected.");

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Google Places API connection failed with error code: "
                + connectionResult.getErrorCode());

        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Google Places API connection failed with error code:" +
                        connectionResult.getErrorCode(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        mPlaceArrayAdapter.setGoogleApiClient(null);
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Google Places API connection suspended.");
    }
}
```

The filter Adapter required and can be customized according to requirement goes like below

```
public class PlaceArrayAdapter
        extends ArrayAdapter<PlaceArrayAdapter.PlaceAutocomplete> implements Filterable {
    private static final String TAG = "PlaceArrayAdapter";
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private AutocompleteFilter mPlaceFilter;
    private LatLngBounds mBounds;
    private ArrayList<PlaceAutocomplete> mResultList;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param context  Context
     * @param resource Layout resource
     * @param bounds   Used to specify the search bounds
     * @param filter   Used to specify place types
     */
    public PlaceArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, LatLngBounds bounds,
                             AutocompleteFilter filter) {
        super(context, resource);
        mBounds = bounds;
        mPlaceFilter = filter;
    }

    public void setGoogleApiClient(GoogleApiClient googleApiClient) {
        if (googleApiClient == null || !googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient = null;
        } else {
            mGoogleApiClient = googleApiClient;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mResultList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public PlaceAutocomplete getItem(int position) {
        return mResultList.get(position);
    }

    private ArrayList<PlaceAutocomplete> getPredictions(CharSequence constraint) {
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Executing autocomplete query for: " + constraint);
            PendingResult<AutocompletePredictionBuffer> results =
                    Places.GeoDataApi
                            .getAutocompletePredictions(mGoogleApiClient, constraint.toString(),
                                    mBounds, mPlaceFilter);
            // Wait for predictions, set the timeout.
            AutocompletePredictionBuffer autocompletePredictions = results
                    .await(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            final Status status = autocompletePredictions.getStatus();
            if (!status.isSuccess()) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error: " + status.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e(TAG, "Error getting place predictions: " + status
                        .toString());
                autocompletePredictions.release();
                return null;
            }

            Log.i(TAG, "Query completed. Received " + autocompletePredictions.getCount()
                    + " predictions.");
            Iterator<AutocompletePrediction> iterator = autocompletePredictions.iterator();
            ArrayList resultList = new ArrayList<>(autocompletePredictions.getCount());
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                AutocompletePrediction prediction = iterator.next();
                resultList.add(new PlaceAutocomplete(prediction.getPlaceId(),
                        prediction.getDescription()));
            }
            // Buffer release
            autocompletePredictions.release();
            return resultList;
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "Google API client is not connected.");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null) {
                    // Query the autocomplete API for the entered constraint
                    mResultList = getPredictions(constraint);
                    if (mResultList != null) {
                        // Results
                        results.values = mResultList;
                        results.count = mResultList.size();
                    }
                }
                return results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    // The API returned at least one result, update the data.
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    // The API did not return any results, invalidate the data set.
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }

    class PlaceAutocomplete {

        public CharSequence placeId;
        public CharSequence description;

        PlaceAutocomplete(CharSequence placeId, CharSequence description) {
            this.placeId = placeId;
            this.description = description;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return description.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Go through the below link which explains each line

[Tutorial with steps explained for Places Suggestion](http://www.truiton.com/2015/04/android-places-api-autocomplete-getplacebyid/)

Comment: I tryed this tutorial, and i think this is exacly where iám looking for. I implemented all the code but the app crashes when i add `<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="My_Key" />`  to my manifest

Comment: You need to put your newly created API_KEY and not the one in sample.

Comment: I know, i used my own API key which i also use for my google maps view. I enabled the Android place API

Comment: bundle gradle also updated with this ? compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0' and synced correctly?

Comment: Yes, i had added this line long before this tutorial ;-), thanks in advance for helping me

Comment: @RoDo Just to make sure all your steps are working fine... Create a separate app only for Autosuggesion places API and see if it works. Then integrate in your actual application. Probably you can find where you are deviating

Comment: Thanks for your help, in a new project everything worked, i deleted the adapter and created it again in the orriginal project and now this works also. I don't know exacly what the problem was but that doesn't matter anymore THANKS, this is the best (and easyes) tutorial by far i follow for this place autocomplete sjizzle :-P

Comment: Hi Sreehari, I have used above code for google places autocomplete textview but I am getting status error in PlacesArrayAdapter(getPredictions() method status error).Please help me on this.

Comment: @Naveen can u give some more insights? More error logs pls

Answer (score 2):

Just Stuck With Google's Places Autocomplete Just Do the Following if you want it like AutoCompleteTextView.its MODE_OVERLAY option.

```
Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_OVERLAY)
                    .build(mActivity);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_AUTOCOMPLETE);
```

Comment: I didn't try this but makes sense. Saves a lot of work!

Comment: How do I retain previously searched item which I can display on second time when user try to search another place?@BajiraoShinde

Comment: assign it globally to perticular string...then after use it @MaulikDodia

Comment: I found the solution. May someone will need it. By `.zzlf(preSearchEntry)` method you can add string which was searched by user previously. Full code is like below.

`String preSearchEntry = "";
Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_OVERLAY)
                    .setBoundsBias(AppConstant.BOUNDS_INDIA)
                    .setFilter(typeFilter)
                    .zzlf(preSearchEntry)
                    .build(getActivity());
            startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);`
@BajiraoShinde

Comment: what are the imports of this?

Answer (score -1):

The Google Play Services version of the Places SDK for Android (in Google Play Services 16.0.0) is deprecated as of January 29, 2019, and will be turned off on July 29, 2019.

```
    Now how we use the **Sreehari** answers with new modifications?
```

If any one know the solution then let me know.Currently i used the android autocomplete 
search process.But still struggling for migrating my old autocomplete places search to new one.

Comment: The Place Picker is deprecated as of January 29, 2019. This feature will be turned off on July 29, 2019, and will no longer be available after that date. To continue using the Place Picker through the deprecation period, do NOT disable the Places SDK for Android in your Google Cloud Platform project, as doing so will also disable the Place Picker.

https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration#compat

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: any new solution for this??

Comment: Hi , just refer the following link for your reference :-
https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration

And the sample program :-
https://github.com/googlemaps/android-places-demos/blob/master/demo/app/src/main/java/com/example/placesdemo/AutocompleteTestActivity.java